# React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Trying to build a ToDo list app in react I'm taking a tutorial to learn React JS, everything was fine but getting the following error in the browser console, can anyone explain help me to solve this, and I'm new to react.

```
index.js:1 Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at App.js:24.
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:172:83)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
react-dom.development.js:25058 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import InputArea from './components/InputArea';
import ToDoItem from './components/ToDoItem';

function App() {
  const [items, setitems] = useState([]);

  const additems = (inputText)=>{
    setitems((prevItems)=>{
      return [...prevItems,inputText];
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="heading">
      <h1>ToDo App</h1>
      </div>
      <InputArea additems={additems} />
      <div>
        <ul>
          {items.map((item, index )=> {
            return <ToDoItem key={index} text={item} />;
            })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And it worked correctly before I have add ToDoItems
**ToDoItems.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const ToDoItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <li>{props.text}</li>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ToDoItem
```

**InputArea.js Code**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const InputArea = (props) => {
    const [inputtext,setinputtext]= useState("");

    const handleChange = (event)=>{
        setinputtext(event.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <div className="form">
            <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={inputtext} />
            <button
            onClick={()=>{
                props.additems(inputtext);
                setinputtext("");
            }}
            >
                <span>Add</span>
            </button>
            
        </div>
    ) 
}

export default InputArea
```

Comment: What;s the structure of your `item`? coming from the items array?

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle (or any other platform) where this issue is reproducible? To make it easier to understand and try to find the solution.

Comment: I've created a quick codesanbox with the code provided and I cannot reproduce your issue. I had to comment out the 'InputArea' component declaration since you did not provide the code for it. Since it's working fine with that line commented, it might be something wrong on that component. Can you provide the code for it? Which React version are you using?

Comment: Item structure is Strings eg: buy milk, homework

Comment: React version is 17.0.2

added InpuArea.js code please check

the main error says "Check your code at App.js:24." and this is my 24th line of code in App.js

{items.map((item, index )=> {
            return <ToDoItem key={index} text={item} />;
            })}

Answer (score 1):

Now it is solved by adding `import React, { useState } from "react";` in App.js file

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error for a different reason - in my App.js file, I was using Routes as such:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>    
    <Route 
      path="/" 
      element={<Home />} 
    />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

But I had nothing written in the corresponding "Home.js" page yet, so the route was reffering to an object that did not yet exist. Entering any exportable content into the "Home.js" file removed the errors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:
export default function(); was with the curly braces, so that was the the issue
!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33742718)

Answer (score 0):

It can be because you may have defined "export default" for a specific component. And when you import in other component file then you may imported using the curly braces like

```
import { header } from '../header.js';
```

So you may get warning.

So for default export just remove curly braces and if you have defined using export only then use curly braces.

Answer (score -1):

I had the error displaying as a white screen. The problem was that I created all my components without putting any contents. As soon as I added texts to the components, the error disappeared